# Detecting a solid color image on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, phantomjs, processing-efficiency

Iam using phantomjs for taking screen-shots but sometimes it fails and produces a solid grey image.

I just want to test whether a image is just a solid colour and if it is make a test fail.

What would be a really simple and efficient way of testing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your image is a PNG, you can use a library like [png.js](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/blob/master/README.md) to extract pixel data and use it in the following way:

```
var PNG = require('png-js');
PNG.decode('some.png', function(pixels) {
    // pixels is a 1d array (in rgba order) of decoded pixel data
});
```

You can then loop through the pixel array checking if each pixel element is identical. If they're all the same, you've got your solid color result.

Comment: thats perfect! thnks.